# using time as a parameter in a conditional statement

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime, conditional-statements

I have an int(value) in a dictionary that continuously gets assigned a new value within a while loop.
I am trying to set a condition whereby if, '(value) < 0' for *x* amount of seconds, how would you go about creating this piece of code?

so, I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
from datetime import time

dict = {"special number": -0.5}

condition = 5

while true:

    if dict["special number"] < 0 'for more than' condition('%S'):

        del(dict)
```

Apologises in advance, I know this *if* statement is far from correct, it was just for example purposes.

kindest regards

Comment: Probably many ways of doing this. One that comes to mind is every time the value is changed assign `time.time()` to a variable then check it periodically. Depends on how accurate you need to be. Searching with `python function call timeout` might give you some ideas.

Comment: Or create a class that can hold your value and starts a countdown when the value is changed -  periodically check if it timed out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to keep track of time yourself. A typical solution might look like this:

1. When the key first hits your target value, start a timer (that is, store the current time in a variable).
2. Every time through the loop, check the value of your key. If the value no longer meets your condition, reset the timer.
3. If the timer expires (i.e., enough time has passed) with the value meeting your condition, perform your desired action.

I would do this with a simple state machine, something like:

```
state = 0
while True:
  if state == 0:
    if dict['special number'] < 0:
      start_time = time.time()
      state = 1
  elif state == 1:
    if dict['special number'] >= 0:
      # value failed condition before timer expired
      state = 0
    elif time.time() - start_time  > 5:
      perform_some_action()
      state = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am getting this right. May be this helps:

```
import time

dict = {"special number": -0.5}
start_time = time.time()

while True:
    if dict["special number"] < 0:
        print("number been less that 0 for {} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time))
    else:
        start_time = time.time()
```